# Saving text from file as variable in Bash

Tags: bash, variables

I have a text file called `test.txt` that looks like this:

```
================
Date = XXXXXX
Path = /path/to/file/
```

I'm writing a bash script that needs to go into `test.txt` and save the directory (not a consistent character length) listed after `Path` and save it as a variable to be used later in the bash script. (i.e. save the file path as `Dir` and and later in the script be able to call `echo $Dir`)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

```
Dir=$(sed -ne 's/^Path *= *//p' test.txt)
```

However many other solutions are possibles

Answer (score 0):

An awk-based possibility:

```
Dir=$(awk '{if ($1 == "Path") print $3}' test.txt)
```

or, if you want to stay purely within bash built-ins:

```
while read var eq value
do  
    if [[ $var = Path ]]
    then
        Dir="$value"
    fi
done < test.txt
```

Comment: Why did you use the "if", rather then the AWK filters? Something like:
    Dir=$(awk '/^Path += +/{print $3}' test.txt)